# OL Office 365 (Win 10) email circle and border issue

Tags: html-email

```
<!--[if mso]>
    <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.EXAMPLE.com/"  style="text-align: center;font-size: 14px;height: 143px;width: 143px;" arcsize="50%" strokecolor="#fbe2a6" strokesize="4px" stroke="f" fillcolor="#f7c54d">
        <w:anchorlock/>
        <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;">
            <div class="yellow-circle">
                <div class="number" style="color: #fff;font-weight: 700;font-size: 24px;line-height: 1;padding-bottom: 2px;">#1</div>
                <div class="round-title" style="font-size: 11px;font-weight: 700;color: #1f3b85;margin-bottom: 5px;">Top Performers<br>on Social Mobility</div>
                <div class="round-title-small" style="color: #1f3b85;font-size: 11px;">2021 US News<br> World Report</div>
            </div>
        </center>
    </v:roundrect>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !mso]> <!-->
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center;background: #f7c54d;font-size: 14px;height: 143px;padding: 0 6px 5px;border-radius: 50%;border: 4px solid #fbe2a6;">
                    <div class="yellow-circle">
                        <div class="number" style="color: #fff;font-weight: 700;font-size: 26px;line-height: 1;padding-bottom: 2px;">#1</div>
                        <div class="round-title" style="font-size: 13px;font-weight: 700;color: #1f3b85;margin-bottom: 5px;">Top Performers<br>on Social Mobility</div>
                        <div class="round-title-small" style="color: #1f3b85;font-size: 13px;">2021 US News<br> World Report</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

[image]
design
now it is look like this
[image]

how to add stroke like in design

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `strokesize="4px"` use `strokeweight="4px"`.

However, you generally want to use points not pixels for Vomit Language (VML). 4px = 4 x 0.75 = 3pt. "Using points also ensures the border will resize properly in Outlook 120DPI." (https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/86)

Also, `stroke="f"` turns off the stroke (and it should be stroked with a d). So change to `stroked="true"`. (HT: https://www.goodemailcode.com/email-enhancements/svg-to-vml, and includes further spec details)